# Auto Complete Form from database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, rdbms

I am trying to create a web/mobile app in which the user has to log in to fill the form once that will be stored in a database. And the next time he logs in, the fields get filled out automatically.
So, I wanted to ask if it is possible or not? And if anyone can help me with this project it would be nice.
And yes, I am new to php and mySql but I have some background in Android.
I want to do this because in our university we have to fill these forms everytime we pay our semester and exam fees.

Comment: Your question is not a standard for stackOverflow? Start your project if you find an error or some problems check if it already answered if not ask a question!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would say is depend on the users browser as it wouldn’t implicate any security issues. `<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" autocomplete="on">`